# How to update records (PUT) in ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, grape-api

I have tried everything I can to get my ember app to update my rails api with zero success.  My current code looks like:
edit route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({ 

  actions: {
        submit: function(){
          var model = this.controller.get('model');
          model.save();
          this.transitionTo('movies.show', model);
     }
   }
});
```

edit.hbs

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{input value=title id=title class="movie-title"}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="director">Director</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{input value=director id="director" class="movie-director"}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="col-sm-2" for="rating">Rating</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{input value=rating id="rating" class="movie-rating"}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block commit-movie-change" {{action 'submit'}}>Add</button>
</form>
```

router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('movies', function(){
    this.route('show', {path: ':movie_id'});
    this.route('edit', {path: ':movie_id/edit'});
    this.route('create', {path: 'create'});
  });
});

export default Router;
```

my model looks like

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  director: DS.attr('string'),
  rating: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This actually works to update locally and start a PUT to the server but it does not send any of the properties/ params to the api. and when i look at the server log it shows

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/movies/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-16 01:00:50 -0500
Movie Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies"  WHERE "movies"."id" = 10 LIMIT 1
 (0.4ms)  BEGIN
 (0.6ms)  COMMIT
```

I am at a loss with this.  I have tried to write `updateRecord()` method within the route but that does not seem to work.  Any help would be hugely appreciated. If you need to see any other code let me know.

Comment: Do you have the Ember Inspector installed? When you enter values in the fields, does the model receive them? If you access the model in the console, change some values, and save it, are the values sent to the server?

Comment: @BuckDoyle I still consider my self a noob so please be patient.  When I look at ember inspect and click on the model it shows the values of the attributes. As for entering data in the console I am not sure how to manipulate the data before i send it

Comment: @BuckDoyle in the console it is saying that my attributes are undefined. Would that mean my submit function, in my edit route, is not defined properly?

Comment: No problem re newbieness. I’m no expert. If you click the $E for the model, the inspector sets the $E variable in the console to the model. Then you can use `$E.set('title', 'a title');` to set the title, and `$E.save()` to save the model. Does the HTTP request contain the attribute?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your back-end is incorrectly parsing the parameters to update the model. In `rails/app/controllers/api/v1/movies.rb`, you have this for a `PUT`:

```
Movie.find_by_id(params[:id]).update_attributes(declared(params[:movie], {include_missing: false}))
```

When I ran both your Ember and Rails applications, I saw that Ember was properly sending attributes to the API, so I added a `binding.pry` in your `put` code to look more closely. There I found that the call to `declared` was filtering out all the attributes. If you change it to this instead, it works:

```
Movie.find_by_id(params[:id]).update_attributes(declared(params, {include_missing: false})[:movie])
```

I’ve never used Grape so I don’t know if this is idiomatic, but it works.

Incidentally, you can just use `Movie.find(params[:id])`; `find_by_id` is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I'm away from my computer at the moment but will update my out method as soon as I can and update the answer once confirmed. On a side note I was beginning to suspect my api being the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In handlebars, try to change direct the references to your `model` to e.g.

```
{{input value=title id=model.title class="movie-title"}}
```

and let us know if it worked :)

Comment: unfortunately that did not work.  I also tried `model.title` in the value field as well but with no success.  There has to be a way and it's crazy that I can't find a solution more easily.

Comment: after this line: `var model = this.controller.get('model');`, what's the result of `this.controller.get('model.title')`? is `this.controller.get('model')._data empty?

Comment: does your model exist in the controller? do you have it defined somewhere?

Comment: applying `this.controller.get('model.title')` breaks the code. And I believe you call `this.controller.get('model')` because the templates have to explicitly go through the controller to get to the model.  My model is defined in my models subfolder. keep in mind I am using ember-cli.

Comment: sorry for asking but are you sure it's not sent to the server? have you checked the http request? e.g. in chrome in Network section in Headers tab? Request payload is what you want to check.

Comment: i'm positive every time i send a request i look at my api to see if the database has been updated and it doesn't. Well let me rephrase before i set my api to not include missing params it would send an empty payload and my whole record would update to null values.

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t posted the code for your model, but I suspect you didn’t define the relevant attributes on it. Ember Data only serialises model attributes that have been declared; you can set any arbitrary property on a model, but it won’t be saved to the server. Your model should look something like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  director: DS.attr('string'),
  rating: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: indeed my model is defined like what you posted.  I can create new records all day long i just cannot update them.  thats what is so frustrating about this section of the code because there really isn't any straight froward examples out there and I apparently am the only one who doesn't get it. such is life

Comment: just tried setting the title and the request was sent but the attributes where still undefined.

Comment: Ah, that was just a guess based on something that happened to me in the past. Well, I have an interview coming up so I can’t think on this further for a while, but we’ll get it figured out eventually, I believe.

Comment: One thought: what do you see when you send the model to the console via the inspector and type `$E.constructor`?

Comment: It returns `my-flicks@model:movie`

Comment: hmm, there goes another theory. Do you have anything in `app/adapters`, `app/serializers`, or `app/transforms`?

Comment: I have an activeModelAdapter with the namespace and host set. Nothing in serializers or transforms

Comment: you can checkout the code as it currently is  https://github.com/micoch/myFlicks.git